# Joining tables in R while adjusting for "ties"

Tags: r

I'm working on a project that analyzes the ROI of people participating in a bunch of contests. For each contest I have a table that has everyone's ranks, and another table that has the payout for a given rank-range. I want to join these two tables to assign everyone a payout based on their ranking, but I'm having issues thinking about how to handle ties. If two people are tied then the payouts are averaged. My tables are in the hundreds of thousands so I want to get the process right for this smaller example.

Rank table example:

```
   id rank
1   A    1
2   B    1
3   C    3
4   D    4
5   E    4
6   F    4
7   G    7
8   H    8
9   I    9
10  J   10
```

Payout table example:

```
  rankMin rankMax payout
1       1       1    100
2       2       3     70
3       4       5     50
4       6       8     20
5       9      10      0
```

End goal:

```
   id rank payout
1   A    1     85 # Two people tied for first, so take average of 1st and 2nd payouts
2   B    1     85
3   C    3     70
4   D    4     40 # Three people tied for 4th, so take average of 4th/5th/6th payouts.
5   E    4     40
6   F    4     40
7   G    7     20
8   H    8     20
9   I    9      0
10  J   10      0
```

My code so far:

```
# Load libraries
library(dplyr)

# Setup the rank table
id <- LETTERS[1:10]
rank <- c(1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10)
finalStandingsDf <- data.frame(id, rank, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Setup the payout table
rankMin <- c(1, 2, 4, 6, 9)
rankMax <- c(1, 3, 5, 8, 10)
payoutAmt <- c(100, 70, 50, 20, 0)
payoutDf <- data.frame(rankMin, rankMax, payoutAmt)

# "Unzip" the payout table to make it easier to join onto rank table
payoutsFixedAll <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(id)){
  rank <- i
  payoutIndex <- min(which(rank <= rankMax))
  payout <- payoutDf[payoutIndex, 3]

  payoutsFixed <- data.frame(rank, payout)

  payoutsFixedAll <- rbind(payoutsFixedAll, payoutsFixed)
}

### Intermittent step to adjust the payoutsFixedAll table to account for ties ###

# Join onto rank table
rankPayoutDf <- finalStandingsDf %>% 
  left_join(payoutsFixedAll, by = c('rank'))
```

Obviously I need to make some sort of adjustment to the payout table so that it gets adjusted properly, but I'm struggling to think of the best way to do so. I think it will involve counting the number of each rank (1: 2, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 3, etc) and somehow making the adjustment from there? I get what needs to be done I'm just struggling to see the path to get there. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular dataset, we can 1) make the payout for each ranking in `payoutDf` and then 2) average the payouts based on the ranking of `finalStandingsDf`.

```
payouts = with(payoutDf, rep(payoutAmt, rankMax - rankMin + 1)) 
finalStandingsDf$payout <- ave(payouts, finalStandingsDf[["rank"]])
finalStandingsDf

   id rank payout
1   A    1     85
2   B    1     85
3   C    3     70
4   D    4     40
5   E    4     40
6   F    4     40
7   G    7     20
8   H    8     20
9   I    9      0
10  J   10      0
```

Comment: Nice approach with `rep`

Comment: Wow I'm very impressed by this. I feel very comfortable with R but I still don't know `with` very well and didn't know `ave` at all. I was just about done with my new approach that added 50 more lines to my already clunky code. Thanks for helping, I'm definitely going to look into `ave` some more

Comment: ```ave``` is similar to ```group_by(...) %>% mutate(...)``` or ```DT[, newvar := ..., by = ...]``` if you're familiar with ```dplyr``` or ```data.table```. And ```with``` is what I picked up here - it gets tiresome to use all these dollar signs sometimes in base :)